# Displaying graphs from within a C# .NET console app?

Tags: c#, .net, graph, console-application

Methods of popping up a simple X-Y graph from within a C# .NET console app?

p.s. I don't mind using a 3rd party plugin (such as like IronPython or Matlab) to take advantage of 3rd party graphing libraries.

Comment: You mean like ASCII-art? Or you would like this console application to open another window which would represent the canvas on which the graph would be drawn?

Comment: Inside the console or do you want to start a Windows application? Using the console won't really give a satisfying result ( IMHO ) as the "resolution" will be terrible ...

Comment: well guys, in MS-DOS we used to play games so there must be a way to draw lines, circles and shapes, not only ASCII charts... :)

Comment: @Davide Piras - you really want to draw into VGA memory, perhaps even via a BIOS call ? ;-)

Comment: I don't, but I guess he does :)

Comment: Thanks guys -   Im not a DOS Philistine who loves nothing more than to play Space Quest I under MS-DOS 6.22 :) I am looking for a way to spawn a proper graphical graph, not ASCII art.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following method to start a console app with a windows form and then display/hide the form as necessary.  Use the form to display the graph bitmap.

[how to run a winform from console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277771/how-to-run-a-winform-from-console-application)