# How to browse to a directory and store the path in a variable

Tags: c#, file, text

I've been wondering how can I browse to a directory and save the selected path to a string variable by using an console application? I have tried a few things but none seemed to work. Here's my code:

```
string path = "";

FolderBrowserDialog fileDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
var result = fileDialog.ShowDialog(); //exception

if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    path = fileDialog.SelectedPath;
}

Console.WriteLine(path);
```

It throws `ThreadStateException` exception at line `3`.

"Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the process."

Comment: Your code looks fine. What's wrong with it?

Comment: Yes it does look fine. Do you mean you want to allow the user to input the path into the console? In that case, use Console.ReadLine();

Comment: Copied and pasted your code, got the desired output.

Comment: I start the program, and nothing happens.. I ran the debugger and it threw me an exception in the third line "var result... ect"

Comment: @Sapphire What exception? Post the exception and stacktrace

Comment: Console applications cannot use Winforms components as out of the box. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277771/how-to-run-a-winform-from-console-application

Comment: An exception contains a Message, a StackTrace and probably an InnerException. Please update your question with full details, not just the name of the exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are attempting to use this in a console application which runs in [`MTA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Multi Threaded Appartment) whereas the `FolderBrowserDialog` control requires [`STA`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680112%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (Single Threaded Appartment).

To put your console application in STA try decorating the `Main` method with the [`[STAThread]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stathreadattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        string path = "";
        var fileDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        var result = fileDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            path = fileDialog.SelectedPath;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(path);
    }
}
```