# How to open a window in console application?

Tags: c#, forms, console, window

I need to display a window in an application, but it is console.

I've tried using:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
```

The code stayed like this.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            _handler += new EventHandler(Handler);
            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(_handler, true);
            ConnectToServer();
            RequestLoop();   
             Application.EnableVisualStyles(); 
             Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
             Application.Run(new Form1());

        }
```

But the window does not open, if I put the code first the window opens, but the console does not execute the command.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                   Application.EnableVisualStyles(); 
                    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                    Application.Run(new Form1());

                _handler += new EventHandler(Handler);
                SetConsoleCtrlHandler(_handler, true);
                ConnectToServer();
                RequestLoop();                      

            }
```

Neither of the two codes works.

In the first code the window does not open.

In second code the window is opened, but the console does not execute the commands

Comment: can you tell us the purpose of the form you are opening

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to run a winform from console application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/277771/how-to-run-a-winform-from-console-application)

Comment: I need to send information from the window to the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Task.Run(() => Application.Run(new Form1()));
```

[image]

Comment: What is happening is that everything after RequestLoop() does not get executed because it is an infinite loop. So you must run your window before the loop of course.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are running console and window in the same thread. When you launch your window, because the thread is the same as the console, the thread is processing the window and not concurrently the console. To run the console and window concurrently (in separate threads):
change

```
Application.Run(new Form1());
```

to

```
Task.Run(() => Application.Run(new Form1()));
```

This will set another thread for your Window and the console will still be processing.
[image]

Comment: It works, i think you are fogent Console.ReadLine(); so the program doesn't get closed. If your console thread gets closed then your window will also be closed:
            Task.Run(() => Application.Run(new Form1()));
            Console.ReadLine();

Comment: The window does not open

Comment: Please, send me your project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, you are forgetting 'Console.ReadLine();', if it is not threre than your console app will be closed, and your window also.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.Run(() => Application.Run(new Form1()));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Put Task.Run(() => Application.Run(new Form1())); before your RequestLoop, before everything.