# OneDrive SDK showing empty White window for OAuth

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, onedrive

I am coding against the `Microsoft.OneDrive.SDK` and I have also included the `Microsoft.OneDrive.SDK.Authentication`. The issue I am having is that I have a console application which opens just a white window where it clearly is prompting me to log in.

#### Code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk;
using Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.Authentication;

namespace SecondTake_OneDrive_SDK
{
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        RunTask().Wait();
    }

    static async Task RunTask(OneDriveClient oneDriveClient = null)
    {
        Task authTask = null;
        if (oneDriveClient == null)
        {
            var msaAuthenticationProvider = new MsaAuthenticationProvider("CLIENT_ID",null, "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf", new[] { "onedrive.readonly", "wl.signin" }, null, new CredentialVault("CLIENT_ID));
            authTask =  msaAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync();
        }
        try
        {
            await authTask;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: while debugging the application, if you put a breakpoint on the line `if( oneDriveClient == null)` - is oneDriveClient still null? I imagine that it isn't. Hence, the program will skip over all that code and jump to the try block below it.

Comment: What is the behavior you are trying to achieve?  Unless you have obtained a token by other means, the user will need to authenticate themselves.

Comment: @ChristopherThomas, I am trying to understand why the I am prompted with a white box but nothing is loaded to it.

Comment: @prestonsmith the `oneDriveClient` is still null since it is a default -- and it is then hitting the if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Digging through the [source code](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-dotnet-msa-auth-adapter/blob/master/src/OneDrive.Sdk.Authentication.Desktop/Web/FormsWebDialog.cs), it looks like the default ui for getting auth details is a Windows Form:

This is a bit new to me, but [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277771/how-to-run-a-winform-from-console-application) on the subject of running Windows Forms from a console app seems to call Application.EnableVisualStyles(); as the first line in Main().

Perhaps this will allow your console app to draw things properly.

Comment: Interesting, however, my logic lives within an `async Task` do you know if there is a way to simply a way to call my `Task` with the `Application.Run()` rather than having to create a new `Form`?

Comment: My background isn't really Win Forms so forgive me if this doesn't make sense in relation to your comment.  msaAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync() from the SDK is trying to create a form for the user to supply credentials (which I assume is the white box you are getting).  If you enable visual styles, does the white box show any content?

Answer (score 0):

`MsaAuthenticationProvider` uses Windows Forms. In order to draw forms correctly, you need to start running a standard messaging loop. This can be done by `Application.Run` method.
Another problem is that by calling `.Wait()` you will make current thread block.

If you don't want to create any forms, you can create your own `ApplicationContext`, use [`Application.Run(ApplicationContext)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor, and then close it manually:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        var appContext = new ApplicationContext();
        RunTask(appContext); // run task asynchronously, pass ApplicationContext
        Application.Run(); // start processing messages
    }

    static async Task RunTask(ApplicationContext appContext, OneDriveClient oneDriveClient = null)
    {
        try
        {
            Task authTask = null;
            if (oneDriveClient == null)
            {
                var msaAuthenticationProvider = new MsaAuthenticationProvider("CLIENT_ID",null, "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf", new[] { "onedrive.readonly", "wl.signin" }, null, new CredentialVault("CLIENT_ID));
                authTask =  msaAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync();
            }

            await authTask;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            appContext.ExitThread(); // stop messaging loop
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can just call an [Application.Run() overload with no parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157900(v=vs.110).aspx) and utilize `.ContinueWith`:

```
class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        RunTask().ContinueWith(t => { Application.Exit(); }); // run task asynchronously, then exit
        Application.Run(); // start processing messages
    }

    static async Task RunTask(OneDriveClient oneDriveClient = null)
    {
        try
        {
            Task authTask = null;
            if (oneDriveClient == null)
            {
                var msaAuthenticationProvider = new MsaAuthenticationProvider("CLIENT_ID",null, "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf", new[] { "onedrive.readonly", "wl.signin" }, null, new CredentialVault("CLIENT_ID));
                authTask =  msaAuthenticationProvider.AuthenticateUserAsync();
            }

            await authTask;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```